# Why can I save VRAM? I just loaded the model twice

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, torch

I made the following simple toy CNN Model.

```
class Test(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3,300,3),
            nn.Conv2d(300,500,3),
            nn.Conv2d(500,1000,3),
        )
        self.fc = nn.Linear(168200000,1)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv(x)
        out = out.view(-1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out
```

and I made following trainer script.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    device = 'cuda'
    
    #Once
    model = Test()
    model.to(device)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()

    #Twice
    model = Test()
    model.to(device)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    for i in range(10):
        optimizer.zero_grad()   
        print('i :', i)
        x = torch.zeros((50,3,64,64), device=device)
        y = torch.ones(50, device=device)
        output = model(x)
        loss = criterion(output, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

I have 12211MB of VRAM.
[image]
If I load model just once, I use 11878MB.[image]
But if I load model twice, I use 9302MB.[image]

I can save the memory 2576MB! I just loaded the model twice.

Why happen this?

Comment: Is this repeatable? I wonder if this means that since the model doesn't fit two times, there is some kind of VRAM paging going on? Does something like that exist?

Comment: Hi kutschkem.Thank u for ur comment.
This is repeatable. And sorry, I don't know well about VRAM paging.

Comment: Maybe try `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`? You'll have better luck getting an answer at discuss.pytorch.org